# Regular expression in jquery allow only one match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Okay, i've got the following problem. I used jquery to test a string with a regular expression. It works all fine, but....

In the Netherlands the zipcodes are 4 digits followed by 2 characters e.g. 1234AB.
Now i use the following regex to find this: `[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}`.

But when someone types 1234AB+948203848 for example. It also return true. And i don't want that! How can i make it return false when it's not 4 digits followed by 2 characters?

Thanks in advance.

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yaterogoya/1/watch)**

Comment: `/^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}$/`. `^` = start of the strings. `$` = end of the string.

Comment: You don't have to use `new RegExp`, just go with regexp literal `var patt = /^\d{4}[A-Z]{2}$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use anchors to indicate the beginning of the word (`^`) and the end of it (`$`):

```
var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}$");
                       ^                ^
```

As per your comments, you also want to capitalize the input. For this, you can use `.toUpperCase()`:

Test ---> [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/labodukuqo/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('[name=postcode]').keyup(function(){
            var str = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
            var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}$");
            var res = patt.test(str);
                console.log(res);
            });
      });
```

Alternatively, you can use `^[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}$` (note the `[a-zA-Z]` part) to check the four letters, no matter  upper or lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

Use anchors `^` and `$`. So your regex would become:

```
/^\d{4}[A-Z]{2}$/
```